# Inner join in update statement throwing errors

Tags: mysql, plsql

I have something like this:

```
UPDATE table set new_id=(SELECT distinct t2.new_id
FROM table t1
inner join (SELECT hn.id,max(hn.id) OVER (PARTITION BY first_name,MIDDLE_NAME,last_name) AS new_id
from table)t2
on t1.id=t2.id);
```

this query is throwing me an error stating that single row sub query returns more than one row.

Please help me with the syntax on to how to update new_id values

Comment: Even after using distinct keyword it is throwing me the same error.

Comment: Your query is bogus.  Oracle ("plsql") doesn't allow `join`s in updates.  MySQL doesn't support window functions.  I would suggest you delete this question and ask another question with sample data and what you want to accomplish.  Tag it correctly and include your SQL attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the exactly problem: "sub query returns more than one row":

```
UPDATE table set new_id=(SELECT distinct t2.ne
                       ^---
```

The subquery can/will return multiple rows, and since you're using it in an equality context (`=`), that is not permetted. If multiple different values/rows are returned, you have to either make the query truly return only one row/one value, or switch to an `IN` query. The `IN` option is not possible, because you're using the multiple values in an your UPDATE, so a limiting the sub-query to a single row is your only option.

Comment: . . There are so many problem with this query that it is not worth attempting an answer.

Comment: Thanks Marc.I am not sure how to limit the query to a single row?Should I use joins?